# Preserving content of source blocks when exporting literate program to HTML with ReadTheOrg

Tags: c++, emacs, org-mode, org-babel, noweb

### Minimal example

I wrote a program in org-mode using literate programming technique with :noweb extension(?). Typical piece of code looks like this:

```
* Section

In order to do foo with bar, we define a function ~do_foo~, which initializes object of a class ~BarParser~ with a value of parameter of the type ~bar_t~.

#+name: section_function_blockname
#+begin_src cpp
void do_foo
( bar_t bar
, <<additional_parameter_to_do_foo>>
) {
  BarParser barParser(bar);

  <<section_function_do_fooBody>>
} 
#+end_src

The function will require additional parameter for the purposes of the /FizzBazz/ module. We will discuss them in a [[*Decoding FizzBazz messages][later_section]].
```

Entire content of the program is stored in a single file, which at the top has `#+SETUP: theme-readtheorg.setup`. The setup file is not the problem, because the HTML generates correctly, only with not the content I want.

### Problem

To generate the code, I use `(org-babel-tangle)`. This produces all the files I'd expect for all the blocks with :tangle parameter. The files have the content I expect them to have and code compiles and runs the way it should.

To generate the documentation I'd like to publish along the code, I use `(org-html-export-to-html)`. What I expected to happen was that either:

1. the `<<tags>>` will get substituted with their expected value, which wouldn't be ideal but at least acceptable, or
2. the `<<tags>>` will be left untouched the way they are presented,when editing the org-file with Emacs.

However the output to `(org-html-export-to-html)` is quite different and unexpected - all the `<<tags>>` are replaced with a newline character. This leaves me with all the code blocks having incorrect content that cannot be understood without either looking at the generated code or original org-file which completely defeats the purpose of the documentation being in the separate file. I cannot force everyone I work with to switch to Emacs to let them browse the documentation!

### Question

As stated above, the problem is with noweb <> being procesed by some call inside `(org-html-export-to-html)`. The question I have regarding this issue is:

**How can I force `(org-html-export-to-html)` to leave the contents of source blocks as they are, without stripping away the noweb `<<tags>>`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need to specify an appropriate `:noweb` header. Try this:

```
#+begin_src cpp :noweb no-export
```

and refer to the [noweb section](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Noweb-Reference-Syntax) in the manual for other values and more details.